# C# warning for unused variable in foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I've got the following code (simplified) :

```
IEnumerable MyFunc(...){
    IAsyncResult res = mSocket.BeginReceive(mReceptionArray, 0, pNbBytes, SocketFlags.None, null, null);
    while (!res.IsCompleted){
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this :

```
foreach(object o in MyFunc());
```

Of course, the compiler complains because `o` is never used. Is there any way around that ?

**EDIT**

The foreach is executed in a coroutine. I need to block the execution of the coroutine until I receive data from a server. I could use a regular Receive(), but this would block all other coroutines, and I can't do that : there are lots of other coroutines running, and blocking this one with Receive or EndReceive would block them.

Anyway, this is *not* a busy-wait.

Any suggestion to refactor the code is more than welcome, I'm not very experienced with C#.

Comment: You can lower the warning level... Or use code that's a  little bit more sensible.

Comment: If you aren't using the returned collection, why are you calling it in this way?

Comment: It's unclear how the code samples are related.  Did you mean for `MyFunc` to be named `SendBytesSynchronous`?

Comment: Do you need (or want to use) `new WaitForFixedUpdate` returned or `o` defined?

Comment: This looks wrong - what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @Henk Could you develop on "saner code" ? How would you do that ?

Comment: @Calvin1602: why does this foreach not block the other coroutines? It looks like a busy-wait. You can use `mSocket.EndReceive(res)` which will suspend that thread until the receive completes as opposed to the busy-wait with the foreach.

Comment: @Calvin1602: how are you "running" these coroutines?

Comment: No idea, Unity does all this behind the scene.

Comment: Having enumerating cause side-effects *always* causes problems.

Comment: @sixlettervariables : It's called Unity now, but yes, Unity3D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a new extension method to consume the sequence and ignore the results. For example:

```
// TODO: Documentation
public static void ConsumeSequence<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    // TODO: Argument validation
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            // Deliberate no-op
        }
    }
}
```

It's then clear in the calling code what you're doing, and that you're *deliberately* just consuming the sequence and ignoring the results.

Like sixlettervariables, it's not really clear that your sequence is an appropriate one, but if you *did* just want to consume a sequence, that's what I'd do.

Comment: It makes more sense in the context of the library that is actually running the enumerations as coroutines: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/WaitForFixedUpdate.html

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I'd normally expect there to be convenience methods already in place in such a library though, if it's a common thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing what you're doing, I really don't think this is what you want. You've implemented a busy-wait using a `foreach` statement. You've stated that this is done so as to not *block* other coroutines, but I cannot see how a busy-wait loop won't block other coroutines as well.

[Every `.Begin*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceive.aspx) has a [corresponding `.End*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b.aspx) which will gracefully suspend execution of the thread until the asynchronous operation completes.

```
// Suspend execution until the receive operation completes
mSocket.EndReceive(res);
```

Comment: Meta comment: I am advocating using `EndReceive` only because for every `Begin*` you should have a corresponding `End*`.

Comment: I don't want to suspend the execution of the thread, only the coroutine.

Comment: Your busy-wait foreach is in effect suspending the execution of the thread. As it stands using `EndReceive` is no different than using your foreach, unless of course you have other code in that foreach you have left out.

Comment: Plenty of other coroutines are running, yes. I should have made this more clear, sorry, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(object o in MyFunc())
    doNothing(o); // avoiding warning
```

And create a blank method:

```
void doNothing(object o){ }
```

Comment: I really, really need WaitForFixedUpdate : a yield return null would kill the coroutine. And isn't `o` read-only in a foreach ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant on Javad_Amiry's answer (which I +1'd by the way):

```
public static void Unused<T>(this T value) { }
```

Because it's an extension method, you can call it from anywhere using the following syntax:

```
foreach (object o in MyFunc())
    o.Unused();
```

Now just in case anyone wonders, I did try adding `[Conditional("NEVER_COMPILE_ME")]` above it, but sadly that causes the warning to come back.

---

By the way, in my experience with Unity, `yield return null` doesn't kill the coroutine at all. But your code is effectively a busy-wait because you're not giving the coroutine to Unity to run - you're running it yourself. With your code, the `WaitForFixedUpdate` object you constructed just comes through as `o` (or `null` does), and you ignore it and go round again; Unity never sees it. If you want Unity to `WaitForFixedUpdate` or whatever else, you have to give it control of the coroutine by calling `StartCoroutine(MyFunc())`. It's an instance method on `MonoBehaviour`, and the coroutine will run to completion as long as the `MonoBehaviour` remains enabled. Hope that clarifies :)

EDIT - I just noticed you said the 'foreach' itself is run inside a coroutine. In that case, you can do this:

```
var subCoroutine = StartCoroutine(MyFunc());
yield return subCoroutine;
```

Or the equivalent one-line version:

```
yield return StartCoroutine(MyFunc());
```

That'll tell Unity to wait for the other coroutine to finish before continuing with this coroutine.

Or you can do this if you need a slightly lower level:

```
foreach (object o in MyFunc())
    yield return o;
```

Comment: (unrelated to the question) Holy cow, you can yield return a StartCouroutine() ?! This is awesome. Thanks ! PS : This is a 2 year old question, so I've no idea why I said that 'yield return null' kills the coroutine, which is very very false.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks odd - why are you bothering to use asychronous I/O methods on the socket when you're immediately blocking until it's finished anyway?

This will suppress your warning:

```
#pragma warning disable 0168
// code goes here
#pragma warning restore 0168
```

But think if there's a better way before you do something like that. See Jon's answer.

Comment: Because this code blocks the current coroutine only. All others keep running. Thanks for pragma.

Comment: Hmmm, OK. Looks a bit like you're using your mReceptionArray across multiple async calls, but I lack the context to comment here.

Comment: No, mReceptioArray is local to the coroutine. But thanks for reading carefuly :)

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient, but certainly short:

```
MyFunc().Any(x => false);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It consumes the entire iterable synchronously, and really is busy-waiting, unlike the OP's original code, which does not busy-wait because it sticks in a "yield return".

Comment: @PaulDuBois Well, OP's original code busy waits (`while (!res.IsCompleted)`) and I don't see how sticking-in ¨yield return¨ achieves "asynchrony". Did you actually mean "deferred execution"? Anyhow, I have concentrated on what was asked (consuming the sequence) and my answer is functionally equivalent to [John Skeet's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7796541/533120), just shorter and probably slightly less efficient.